# Coldfusion 2021 missing generateGetPresignedUrl method

Tags: amazon-s3, coldfusion

Running Coldfusion 2021 Enterprise.
Adobe docs tell me that the AWS S3 generateGetPresignedUrl() method can be called. Yet I get

> The generatePutPresignedUrl method was not found

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
s3Object = getCloudService("s3Cred", "s3Conf");
bucketObject = s3Object.root(*myRootBucketName*, false);
myFile = bucketObject.generateGetPresignedUrl({"key": *myKey*})
```

Comment: Looking at this post from Ben Nadel (https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2653-using-beforeupload-to-generate-per-file-amazon-s3-upload-policies-using-plupload.htm), it looks like the key argument is just an argument, not a key collection.  The current Adobe docs, though, show a struct.  Since you're only sending the key argument, just try it as a simple arg, not as a key in a struct.  Report back, please.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Same error. generateGetPresignedUrl method not found.

Comment: I'm guessing that root function doesn't return the same object as just getting the bucket. This could be a bug. Does it work with the createBucket() function?

Comment: That's the reason @haxtbh. The generateGetPresignedUrl() method is only available with createBucket(). Ugh. Thanks for the troubleshooting tips.